# Select 1 pr S/N where customer ID = x and the newest one

Tags: php, mysql, network-printers

I can't really get a picture of how i should proceed getting the following information out from mysql.

I click on a customer. And on the new page i get the basic customer information, and the plan is also to get a overview over printers attached to the customer. 
i have a database, where printers reports their information to, once a day.

i only want to show each machine once(per S/N), with the newest information like counter, toner etc...

```
S/N     Model                  Counter Current Cyan Current Magenta Current Yellow Current Black
NB64534 HP Color Laserjet 2600  65.473          45%             32%            87%           33%
NB54730 HP Color Laserjet 2530 876.645          20%             10%            33%           99%
```

The code above is only a fictional, but they way i would like to be able to present the machines for each customer.

it has been a while since i last worked with php and mysql, so i am properly not up to date on the code.

At the moment, i have nothing close to what i want, only a basic Mysql string. `$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM maskine WHERE K_ID = 1 ORDER BY  date DESC');`

Comment: Can you provide us the query you have at this moment? Probably you need a GROUP BY and ORDER BY to get the expected result

Comment: At the moment, i have nothing close to what i want, only a basic Mysql string. 
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM maskine WHERE K_ID = 1 ORDER BY DESC');

Comment: I'm not sure what your S/N column is, so for now I assumed serial_number, same for creation_date (if you want to order on that). This should do it: SELECT * FROM maskine WHERE K_ID = 1 GROUP BY serial_number ORDER BY creation_date DESC

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this and [edit] your question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: MySQL is already handling that for you. You only get 1 row per GROUP BY (combination). So if you loop the results, you should only see one row per S/N

Comment: @AliAlwash - Yeah, just figured that out! 
Thanks!! works perfect! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on our comment conversation, the end result is (assuming serial_number is your S/N column and you want to order on creation_date)

```
SELECT * FROM maskine WHERE K_ID = 1 GROUP BY serial_number ORDER BY creation_date DESC
```

// Edit

**Sorting on creation_date**

Ignore my previous query, GROUP BY and ORDER BY in one query doesn't work as expected.
This should do it, the inner query selects all queries where K_ID = 1 and order by creation date. The outer query will group the results on the S/N.

```
SELECT result.*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM maskine
      WHERE K_ID = 1
      ORDER BY creation_date DESC) result
GROUP BY result.serial_number;
```

Comment: I have a question about the SQL string, when i get the group output, how can i sort so that i get the newest column shown, i have a timestamp i am trying to sort after, but i can't get it to show the right value. 

my current string looks like this: $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM maskine WHERE SN IN (SELECT SN FROM link WHERE KN=$k[id])GROUP BY SN ORDER BY TS DESC"); 

I have a value in a row that is 18, but it should have been the row with 16, as this is the newest row, and have the highest timestamp value.

Comment: @K.Svane I'v changed my answer with the query that should help you.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `maskine` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `SN` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `MN` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `HN` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `scan` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `total` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `A3C` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `A3M` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `A4C` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `A4M` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `C` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `M` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Y` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `K` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `K_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `dato` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `TS` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `kunder` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `k_navn` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `k_vej` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `k_post` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `k_h_tlf` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `k_tlf` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `k_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `k_peron` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `link` (
  `SNN` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `KN` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: These 3 tables are working together, i have the kunder list, where customers is in, i have the maskine table, which is printers, and i have the link table, the link is used to identify wich printer relates to which customer. 

I want to get printers assigned to a specific customer, listing latest values in eg. C, M, Y, K. 

And i get what i need, except the latest values.